# dynamic column selection based on cell value

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

i have a questions database of the shape

```
ID , Question , Answer1 , Answer2 , Answer3 , Answer4 , True
```

where "True" is the index of the correct answer:

```
True = 0 --> Answer1
....
True = 3 --> Answer4
```

i need to select only the question and the correct answer, this is what i got so far:

```
SELECT Question , 'Answer' || (True+1) From Questions
```

but it returns the question and 'answer1' or 'answer2' ... ie: the name of the column i need not it's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CASE` in MySQL.

```
SELECT  Question,
        CASE True
            WHEN 0 THEN Answer1
            WHEN 1 THEN Answer2
            WHEN 2 THEN Answer3
            WHEN 3 THEN Answer4
        END AS Answer
FROM    tableName
```

OR

```
SELECT  Question,
        CASE 
            WHEN TRUE = 0 THEN Answer1
            WHEN TRUE = 1 THEN Answer2
            WHEN TRUE = 2 THEN Answer3
            WHEN TRUE = 3 THEN Answer4
        END AS Answer
FROM    tableName
```

Comment: @workoverflow i have updated the answer. try it on sqlite which one will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second one worked on both the mySQL and SQLite, but the first worked only on mySQL.

Comment: just wondering, is there a way to do it without having to list all the cases? like the way i tried to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can refactor the database schema, you could change it to this:

QuestionID, QuestionText, AnswerID, AnswerText, IsCorrect

To get the right answer, use this query:

Select * from Questions where QuestionID = X and IsCorrect = True

To get all answers, use this query:

Select * from Questions where QuestionID = X

And now you can have as many or as few answers for a question as you please.

Comment: Actually the database is gigantic and it would be a waste of time refactoring it while it can be done with a query, but thanks for the thought.

Comment: Yeah, there's always two kinds of answers, the 'this would be great if I had more time' answer and the 'this works right now' answer XD